# Could not build the precompiled application for the device. Error launching application on iPhone - Flutter

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, compiler-errors

I can't run my flutter project on an IOS device.

This is what I got after flutter run. I can't understand why. Please have a look at the error below and tell me how to fix this. (Have to paste it into pastebin, stackoverflow tells me that the error is too big..)

[Pastebin Error Source](https://pastebin.com/7nL6AyZw)

What can I do to fix this problem? Please give me a command line or sth. Please help me. I am looking forward to hearing from you. Thank you.

```
Error launching application on iPhone.
Exited (sigterm)
```